# Error when trying to connect to another windows machine: "<computer_name> is not accessible. You may not have permission to use this network resource"

Tags: windows, networking

I have two windows machines in my network. I can see the secondary one through the network discovery, but when I click it I get an error '<computer_name> is not accessible. You may not have permission to use this network resource'

Comment: Make sure File and Print sharing is enabled and also that computer name is in your Host File.

Comment: That helped. It looked like I had sharing enabled for private networks, but there was another option under 'All Networks' which was overriding the private settings. There was no need to add the computer name to the host file.